# too many initializer values c++

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

Could someone explain why i'm getting the following compiler error:

*error: too many initializers for ‘std::array<std::array<State, 2>, 8>*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

enum State
{
  NONE,
  WHITE,
  BLACK
};


int main()
{

  array<array<State, 2>, 8> initial = {
    { State::NONE, State::NONE },
    { State::WHITE, State::WHITE },
    { State::NONE, State::NONE },
    { State::NONE, State::NONE },
    { State::NONE, State::NONE },
    { State::NONE, State::NONE },
    { State::BLACK, State::BLACK },
    { State::NONE, State::NONE }
  };

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just need an additional pair of [braces](https://godbolt.org/z/GddG1a).

Comment: It's interesting that clang literally calls `memset` to null the array, then sets the non-zero fields. I checked gcc too, and it sets each individual field instead, as you'd most likely expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a normal array like so :

```
State ini[8][2] = {
   { State::NONE, State::NONE },
  { State::WHITE, State::WHITE },
  { State::NONE, State::NONE },
  { State::NONE, State::NONE },
  { State::NONE, State::NONE },
  { State::NONE, State::NONE },
  { State::BLACK, State::BLACK },
  { State::NONE, State::NONE }
};
```

or to fix your code add a pair of brackets :

```
 array<array<State, 2>, 8> initial = { {
      {State::NONE, State::NONE },
      { State::WHITE, State::WHITE },
      { State::NONE, State::NONE },
      { State::NONE, State::NONE },
      { State::NONE, State::NONE },
      { State::NONE, State::NONE },
      { State::BLACK, State::BLACK },
      { State::NONE, State::NONE }
    } };
```